# How can I change the default preview device in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I'm creating a new project, the default preview device appears as Nexus 4. Is there a way to change it to some other device?

Comment: What sort of things have you researched/tried, for changing that default preview?

Answer (score 8):

Recently I had the same issue. 
It seems that you cannot use a device from the "virtual device" category. That way only the selected layout will be shown inside the chosen device.

In order to change the default device for all layouts you have to choose from some of the other categories (the ones inside the red rectangle):

[image]

I have chosen "6.0 1440 x 2560" from "Phone" and all my other layouts changed to this device (before I was selecting "Nexus6_API_29_Android" which was my virtual device, and I had to change it on every layout manually)

Comment: Works for me, thanks! I got sick of seeing my previews on a 4K TV...

Answer (score 4):

Same issue was appearing for me, when I was selecting device for preview from 'Virtual Device'.

To select device which will be default for preview when opening activities choose from these in picture, which are marked in red rectangles.

[image: default_device]

Answer (score 2):

1. Change the preview device>>for example: nexus5x or others.
2. File--Export Setting, then choose a dictionary to save it. For example, I save it on my desktop, next you will see a `settings.jar` on your desktop.
3. File-Import Setting, choose the `settings.jar`.
4. Android Studio will want to restart itself, click OK

My English is very poor. I'm so sorry.
Maybe it works well. I'm not sure. You can try it.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer covers most cases.
But if you want to use a custom made device you can also click on the `Generic Phones and Tablets` option, and choose your device from there.

[image: Generic Phones and Tablets Dropdown]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to follow few steps to do this

**Step One**

Open Any layout file from

App >> res >> layout directory

**Step Two**

go to the above red marking option

Then you will find the available devices for change

[image]

N.B. I am using Android Studio 3.6.2

Answer (score -1):

Go to Run -> Edit Configurations. "Under Deployment Target Options", de-select "Use same device for future launches." 
[image]

To prevent the same device from being used on subsequent previews, when you create a new project and run it in the AVD, do not select "use the same device."
[image]

Comment: This is not what I mentioned. I meant preview device as layout preview. Not for launches. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @KutsanKaplan, sorry about that. I have tried changing the device in the "Preview" section for layouts. It appears that I only have to change it the first time. When I close Android Studio and relaunch the project, it did save the new device.

Comment: For me, it keeps the same preview device but starts in portrait every single time. When you use a tablet preview, you kind of want it in landscape.