# default preview device and orientation

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio (BumbleBee 2021.1.1).

I have created a device in the Device Manager which corresponds to the physical tablet that I am connecting to each time.

However, each time I open up a project, the default view in the Design view is for a Pixel phone, in Portrait mode.

How can I set it to use my device in landscape mode, as the default, instead of having to manually set this every time I open the project?

Thanks

Garrett

Comment: Nobody got anything on this...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the default preview device in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783616/how-can-i-change-the-default-preview-device-in-android-studio)

Comment: no, there are too many changes from that version